# How to run corssbar without using "crossbar start" command

Tags: python, django, websocket, wamp-protocol, crossbar

I'm trying to understand crossbar and I want to make a kind of demonstration for my blog which is made with Django (python).
My demo works fine but I don't get it: how to make crossbar solution working without needing to use the "crossbar start" command.
I mean, I would like crossbar to be detached as my Apache server does. Isn't it possible ?

PS: I'm using Django 1.7, Apache 2.4 on Debian 8.

Comment: Ok I finnaly fix my problem but I'm not really satisfied of it. Anyway, I just followed the crossbar tutorial about putting crossbar in production : http://crossbar.io/docs/Automatic-startup-and-restart/

Comment: Something also needs to start you Apache server (probably a daemon or script), and the same can be used for Crossbar.io. I don't know what you mean by "detached" though.